# How to use Value constructors to create records in PureScript

Tags: adt, record, purescript

I am attempting to create a record based on an array of data, the function looks like this:

```
type Address = {
  street :: String,
  city :: String,
  state :: String
}

convertToAddress :: Array String -> Maybe Address
convertToAddress [street, city, state] = Just (Address { street: street, city: city, state: state })
convertToAddress _ = Nothing
```

Here, I am trying to create a Record of the type Address using the Address value constructor but it throws an error when compiling:

```
Unknown data constructor Address
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`type` only defines a type alias, so `Address` and

```
{
  street :: String,
  city :: String,
  state :: String
}
```

Are actually the same type. If you want to generate a constructor you will have to use `newtype`:

```
newtype Address = Address {
  street :: String,
  city :: String,
  state :: String
}
```

Or alternatively, you can just get rid of the constructor in your code and just use the record type:

```
convertToAddress :: Array String -> Maybe Address
convertToAddress [street, city, state] = Just { street: street, city: city, state: state }
convertToAddress _ = Nothing
```